# How do I fix weird looking smoothed faces?

Tags: faces, edges, retopology, smooth

I have been modeling this for a couple hours now and I have yet to retopologize the model but I was messing around with settings under Mesh/Shading/ And all those settings under there. I don't know exactly what happened here but it looks like smooth shading with creased edges, but I can't find anything on how to fix it and I feel like I've pressed every button and gone through all the settings and I can't fix this.

It looks like this in all render modes and and both cycles and Eevee.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file or at least a part of your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: As @moonboots says we'd need to see you Blend file, but have you tried checking Auto Smooth Normals under Object Data Properties (green triangle) > Normals? Difficult to see from the image but it also looks as if you have poor topology on your model.